# BrowserSync file changes are not propagated with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, browser-sync

I'm using a vagrant box (Varying Vagrant Vagrants) on Windows. I'm using the latest Virtualbox with proper guest addons (5.0.26).

I have the following settings in my Vagrantfile

```
# Browsersync port forward
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000, auto_correct: true
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3001, host: 3001, auto_correct: true
```

Using this command:

```
browser-sync start --proxy "sitename.dev" --files "assets/css/*.css"
```

The browsersync initialized properly. When I change the css files directly in the virtual machine everything is ok the css is being injected in my browser.
**When I change the files in the host file system nothing happens. The browser sync is not aware of the file changes** (The files synchronized properly between host and virtual filesystems).

I tried with nfs and simple Virtualbox synced folders too. (Not just with NFS that describet here: https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/issues/368)

How can I get this working?

**EDIT:**
I've got this working and answered my question according to it.
BTW this solution is working with NFS too and not related to the host OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution described here: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/318#issuecomment-98355661 by @faergeek

Just need to add **usePolling: true** to your bs-config.js like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "files": 'assets/css/*.css',
    "watchOptions": {
        usePolling: true
    },
    "proxy": ''
};
```

And start browser-sync like this:

```
browser-sync start --config bs-config.js
```